# How to get a response for IPC Main from IPC Renderer

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipc

I know how to send message from Main to renderer process and also calling main from renderer.
However, I am having trouble replying to main from renderer

Renderer

```
ipcRenderer.invoke('IPC_HANDLE', "ping").then((result) => {

        console.log("from renderer", result) 

 })
```

Main.js

```
 ipcMain.handle('IPC_HANDLE', async (event, args) => {
     const data  = args // ping

    return "pong"

 })
```

what I want to do now is send message from Main to Renderer and wait for a response. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args

Comment: Why dont you send another event from ipcRenderer, for example `IPC_HANDLE_SUCCESS` or `IPC_HANDLE_FAIED`?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no function similar to [`ipcRenderer.invoke()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) for the main process. IE: An individual function that sets up a channel to send a message to the render process **and receive a message in response**.

To do this, 2 individual channels need to be used. One to receive the main process message ([`window.ipcRenderer.on()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendereronchannel-listener)) and within that, the second, to send a message back to the main process ([`window.ipcRenderer.send()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)) (on a different channel).

---

`preload.js` (main process)

> This `preload.js` script is only used to setup whitelisted channel names. All concrete implementations of functions these chanels call are setup within other main process scripts (not the `preload.js` script). This seperates concerns and keeps things simple and organised.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'render-to-main'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [
            'main-to-render'
        ],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': [
            'render-to-main-to-render'
        ]
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodePath = require("path");

let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('main-to-render', 'Ping 1 (send from main process)'); })
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.on('render-to-main', (event, message) => {
    console.log(message); // Pong 1 (send from render process)
});

electronIpcMain.handle('render-to-main-to-render', (event, message) => {
    console.log(message); // Ping 2 (invoke from render process)
    return 'Pong 2 (handle from main process)';
});
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="ping-main-process">Ping main process: </label>
        <input type="button" id="ping-main-process" value="Ping 2">
    </body>

    <script>
        // Receive message from main process.
        window.ipcRender.receive('main-to-render', (result) => {
            console.log(result); // Ping 1 (send from main process)
            // Manually reply to main process (on a different channel)
            window.ipcRender.send('render-to-main', 'Pong 1 (send from render process)');
        });

        // Invoke, sends message and waits for reply.
        document.getElementById('ping-main-process').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.invoke('render-to-main-to-render', 'Ping 2 (invoke from render process)')
                .then((result) => { console.log(result); }) // Pong 2 (handle from main process)
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well a few days ago, and I actually got it to work, and what you need to do is expose the ipcRenderer in the preload script.
so you would have something like this

Preload.js

```
const { ipcRenderer,contextBridge} = require("electron");
const ipc = ipcRenderer;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
   sendMessage: (args) => ipc.invoke('message',args),
   
})
```

renderer.js

```
btn = document.getElementById("send-submit");
btn.addEventListener("click", async ()=>{
const mes = "ping";
api.sendMessage(mes).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);
});
```

main.js

```
  ipc.handle('message', async (e,msg) => {
  console.log(msg + " recieved");
  
  return("pong");
})
```

this got it working for me, Hope it does for you too.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your solution explains renderer->main communication (i.e. how to invoke an event in main from something triggered in the renderer). However the original question is asking the inverse.